# OneDrive not running automatically on Windows 10 because of Registry setting

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, onedrive

Every time I reboot Windows 10 the registry setting

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\OneDrive

Is reset by windows 10 to value

DisableFileSyncNGSC = DWORD:1

Which means that OneDrive does not run until I manually change the Registry DWORD setting back to zero.

Is there a way to permanently set this Registry value to zero so OneDrive runs without intervention?

Comment: Is this machine connected to an Active Directory domain by chance?

Comment: Is Group Policy setting the regkey back?

Comment: Hi. This is a home machine that is not part of a Windows domain.

Comment: I bet you guys are on the right path.  Try running "GPEDIT.MSC", navigate to Computer Configuration | Administrative Templates | Windows Components | OneDrive, Then check out the settings.. specifically "Prevent the usage of OneDrive for file storage"

Comment: @Senor CMasMas . Gpedit.msc fixed the problem. Can you post as an answer and I will accept it?

Comment: Thank you @CliveLong. :)  I am glad that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running "GPEDIT.MSC"

***First, navigate to:***

Computer Configuration | Administrative Templates | Windows Components | OneDrive

***Then check out the settings.. specifically:***

- Prevent the usage of OneDrive for file storage